# magento 2 too many js call inspite of bundling

Tags: magento2, jsbundling

i have enabled production mode and bundling also yet i am seeing to many js file call aroun 120 plus that is causing issue with load time

[image: 2]

Comment: you can Easily exclude js from bundle or you can increase bundle size from etc/view.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can execute below commands in your magento root console to merge and bundle javascript files.

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 1
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 1
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 1
```

Then execute compilation and static content deploy on your console and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: i am getting below 

 There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace.
  Did you mean one of these?
      setup:config
      setup:store-config

Comment: Which magento version are you using?

Comment: magento 2.1.5.........

Comment: Okay, no problem, just enable merge, bundle and minify javascript from admin panel configuration section. Then execute setup upgrade and static content deploy commands. Flush cache and check

Comment: these are already done view source shows only one js but gtmetrix shows about 127 js files